# Cloud Firestore Nested arrays are not supported Error Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to import json to my cloud firestore collection, which contains nested array, but even with FieldValue.arrayUnion function getting error "Invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported".

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('universities2')
              .doc(value.docs.first.id)
              .update({
            'departments': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
              json["Sayfa1"][0][x]["department"][0]["name"],
              json["Sayfa1"][0][x]["department"][0]["fields"]
            ])
          });
```

Is there any way to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

In `node.js` using with spread operator`(...)` or `.apply(this, array)` is working, example:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('universities2')
              .doc(value.docs.first.id)
              .update({
            'departments': FieldValue.arrayUnion(...[
              json["Sayfa1"][0][x]["department"][0]["name"],
              json["Sayfa1"][0][x]["department"][0]["fields"]
            ])
          });
```

or

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('universities2')
              .doc(value.docs.first.id)
              .update({
            'departments': FieldValue.arrayUnion.apply(this, [
              json["Sayfa1"][0][x]["department"][0]["name"],
              json["Sayfa1"][0][x]["department"][0]["fields"]
            ])
          });
```

Comment: Let me know if this answer is also working in Flutter.